# Align equations in table

Tags: tables, equations, align

I'd like to align the equations inside my table. They should start all together left (as it is now) and should be aligned to the `=` sign.
[image]

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%%----- Tabellen -------------------------------
\usepackage{longtable}                      % Tabellen über mehrere Seiten
\usepackage{array}                              % erweitern Tabelleneigenschaften   
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.0} % Default value: 1
\begin{tabular}{|ll|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Maschinenmodell einer PMSM\\[-2ex] im dreiphasigen ($a, b, c$)-Koordinatensystem\end{tabular}}}\\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Statorkreis:}         & $u_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}(t) = R_{\mathrm{s}} \cdot i_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}(t) + \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \psi_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}(t)$ \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{verkettete Flüsse:}   & $\psi_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}(t) = \psi_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}\left(i_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}(t), \phi_{\mathrm{m}}(t)\right)$ \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Mechanik:}            & $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \omega_{\mathrm{m}}(t) = \frac{1}{\theta_{\mathrm{m}}} \cdot \left(m_{\mathrm{m}}(t) - m_{\mathrm{l}}(t) \right)$ \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{elektrische Signale:} & $\omega_{\mathrm{el}}(t) = p \cdot \omega_{\mathrm{m}}(t) \quad \textrm{und} \quad \phi_{\mathrm{el}}(t) = p \cdot \phi_{\mathrm{m}}(t)$ \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Moment:}              & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}$m_{\mathrm{m}}(t) = p \cdot i_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}(t)^{T} \cdot J_{\sum} \cdot \psi_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}(t) \quad \textrm{mit} \quad i_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}(t)^{T} = \left( i_{\mathrm{s}}^{a}(t), i_{\mathrm{s}}^{b}(t), i_{\mathrm{s}}^{c}(t) \right)$\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Maschinenmodell einer PMSM im dreiphasigen ($a, b, c$)-Koordinatensystem (1)}
\label{tab: Maschinenmodell_PMSM_abc_Tabelle_1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

How can this be done?

Comment: The long expression in the bottom right cell makes the `tabular` environment exceed the width of the textblock, aka `\textwidth`. Incidentally, why are you using `tabular` environments in the cells in the right-hand column, and what is the purpose of the `\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{...}` wrappers in the left-hand column?

Comment: Off-topic: Is `J_{\sum}` correct? Should it maybe be `J_{\Sigma}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you ditch the two-column `tabular` approach and, instead, employ an `alginedat{3}` environment. I would also provide for a more open "look" by getting rid of all vertical lines and most horizontal lines. The table, somewhat weirdly, appears to have two caption -- the latter numbered, the former unnumbered. I suggest creating only one caption per table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable,array,amsmath,booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{justification=Centering,skip=0.333\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht] 
\caption{Maschinenmodell einer PMSM im dreiphasigen 
        ($a, b, c$)-Koordinatensystem (1)}
\label{tab:Maschinenmodell_PMSM_abc_Tabelle_1}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l @{}} % allow use of \toprule and \bottomrule
\toprule
$\begin{alignedat}{3}
&\text{Statorkreis} && 
&u_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}(t) &= 
R_{\mathrm{s}} \cdot i_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}(t) + \tfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \psi_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}(t) \\ \addlinespace 
&\text{Verkettete Flüsse} && 
&\psi_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}(t) &= 
\psi_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}\bigl(i_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}(t), \phi_{\mathrm{m}}(t)\bigr) \\ \addlinespace 
&\text{Mechanik} &\qquad& 
&\tfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \omega_{\mathrm{m}}(t) &= 
\tfrac{1}{\theta_{\mathrm{m}}} \cdot \bigl(m_{\mathrm{m}}(t) - m_{\mathrm{l}}(t) \bigr) \\ \addlinespace 
&\text{Elektrische Signale} &&
&\omega_{\mathrm{el}}(t) &= 
p \cdot \omega_{\mathrm{m}}(t) \quad\text{und}\quad \phi_{\mathrm{el}}(t) = p \cdot \phi_{\mathrm{m}}(t) \\ \addlinespace 
& \text{Moment} &&
&m_{\mathrm{m}}(t) &= 
p \cdot i_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}(t)^{T} \cdot J_{\Sigma} \cdot \psi_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}(t) \text{ mit} \\ 
 &&&&&\qquad i_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}(t)^{T^{\mathstrut}} = 
 \bigl( i_{\mathrm{s}}^{a}(t), i_{\mathrm{s}}^{b}(t), i_{\mathrm{s}}^{c}(t) \bigr)
\end{alignedat}$\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Another question: How can I reduce the space around `\cdot`?

Comment: @Domi1908 -- My preferred recommendation would be to simply omit `\cdot` entirely or, at least, to replace it with `\,` ("thinspace"). Seriously, give omitting the `\cdot` directives a try. If you prefer to eliminate the whitespace around `\cdot`, just encase it in curly braces, i.e., write `{\cdot}`.

Comment: Is it possible to put `mit` also in the next line and align it to the `und`?

Comment: @Domi1908 - Do you just want `\text{mit}` on a line by itself? Or shoud `\text{mit } i_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}(t)^{T^{\mathstrut}} =  \bigl( i_{\mathrm{s}}^{a}(t), i_{\mathrm{s}}^{b}(t), i_{\mathrm{s}}^{c}(t) \bigr)` all be together on one line? (Hint: the latter won't fit inside the text block if you also want the words `und` and `mit` aligned vertically...) A suggestion: Would it be acceptable to align the `=` symbols on the final two lines, with `\mit` moved to the final line? That would be trivially easy to accomplish.

Comment: `\text{mit } i_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}(t)^{T^{\mathstrut}} =  \bigl( i_{\mathrm{s}}^{a}(t), i_{\mathrm{s}}^{b}(t), i_{\mathrm{s}}^{c}(t) \bigr` should be all together on one line.

Comment: @Domi1908 — and where should the vertical alignment occur?

Comment: Doesn't matter anymore:)

Answer (score 6):

I put the part of the equation to the left of the `=` in a separate `r` column and put a `{}` before the `=` sign to get proper spacing.

I also did some cleanup.

**EDIT: Split the last equation over two lines.**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%%----- Tabellen -------------------------------
\usepackage{longtable}                      % Tabellen über mehrere Seiten
\usepackage{array}                              % erweitern Tabelleneigenschaften   
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.0} % Default value: 1
\begin{tabular}{|l|r@{}l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Maschinenmodell einer PMSM}}\\[-2ex]
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{im dreiphasigen ($a, b, c$)-Koordinatensystem}}\\ \hline
Statorkreis:         & $u_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}(t)$ & ${}= R_{\mathrm{s}} \cdot i_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}(t) + \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \psi_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}(t)$ \\ \hline
verkettete Flüsse:   & $\psi_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}(t) $ & ${}= \psi_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}\left(i_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}(t), \phi_{\mathrm{m}}(t)\right)$ \\ \hline
Mechanik:            & $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \omega_{\mathrm{m}}(t) $ & ${}= \frac{1}{\theta_{\mathrm{m}}} \cdot \left(m_{\mathrm{m}}(t) - m_{\mathrm{l}}(t) \right)$ \\ \hline
elektrische Signale: & $\omega_{\mathrm{el}}(t) $ & ${}= p \cdot \omega_{\mathrm{m}}(t) \quad \textrm{und} \quad \phi_{\mathrm{el}}(t) = p \cdot \phi_{\mathrm{m}}(t)$ \\ \hline
Moment:              & $m_{\mathrm{m}}(t) $ & ${}= p \cdot i_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}(t)^{T} \cdot J_{\sum} \cdot \psi_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}(t) $ \\
                     &   & $\phantom{{}={}} \quad \textrm{mit} \quad i_{\mathrm{s}}^{abc}(t)^{T} = \left( i_{\mathrm{s}}^{a}(t), i_{\mathrm{s}}^{b}(t), i_{\mathrm{s}}^{c}(t) \right)$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Maschinenmodell einer PMSM im dreiphasigen ($a, b, c$)-Koordinatensystem (1)}
\label{tab: Maschinenmodell_PMSM_abc_Tabelle_1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can split the last equation over two lines. See Zarko's solution, or just use two rows. I have edited my solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll think about which solution fits best to my work.

Answer (score 4):

With use of the `tabularray` and `mathtools` packages; with similar table design as in @Pieter van Oostrum answer (+1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip, 
            font=small]{caption}
%%%----- Tabellen -------------------------------
\usepackage{tabularray}   
%%%----- Math. und Index Abkürzung --------------
\usepackage{mathtools}
    \newcommand\el{el}
    \newcommand\ud{\mathrm{d}}
    \newcommand\dt{\,\ud t}
    \newcommand\m{\mathrm{m}}
    \newcommand\s{\mathrm{S}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vline{1,2,Z},
             colspec = {l Q[r, mode=math] @{\;} X[l, mode=math]},
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries, c},
             rowsep=5pt
             }
\SetCell[c=3]{c}    {Maschinenmodell einer PMSM\\
                     im dreiphasigen ($abc$)-Koordinatensystem}
                    &   &                   \\ 
Statorkreis:        & u_{\s}^{abc}(t)
                        & = R_{\s} \cdot i_{\s}^{abc}(t) + \frac{\ud}{\dt} \psi_{\s}^{abc}(t)   \\ 
verkettete Flüsse:  & \psi_{\s}^{abc}(t)
                        & = \psi_{\s}^{abc}\Bigl(i_{\s}^{abc}(t),\ \phi_{\m}(t)\Bigr)               \\
Mechanik:           & \frac{\ud}{\dt} \omega_{\m}(t)
                        & = \frac{1}{\theta_{\m}} \cdot \bigl(m_{\m}(t) - m_{\mathrm{l}}(t) \bigr)  \\
Elektrische Signale:& \omega_{\el}(t)
                        & = p \cdot \omega_{\m}(t) 
                            \quad \textrm{und} \quad 
                            \phi_{\el}(t) = p \cdot \phi_{\m}(t)                            \\ 
Moment:              & m_{\m}(t)
                        & = \begin{multlined}[t][0.8\linewidth]
                            p \cdot i_{\s}^{abc}(t)^{T} \cdot J_{\sum} \cdot \psi_{\s}^{abc}(t) \\
                             \textrm{mit} \quad 
                                i_{\s}^{abc}(t)^{T} = \left( i_{\s}^{a}(t), 
                                i_{\s}^{b}(t), i_{\s}^{c}(t) \right)
                            \end{multlined}                                                        \\ 
\end{tblr}
\caption{Maschinenmodell einer PMSM im dreiphasigen ($abc$) - Koordinatensystem (1)}
\label{tab: Maschinenmodell_PMSM_abc_Tabelle_1}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**

- Considered is @Mico comment (thank you very much for pointing me on this mismatch)
- Added is version where the first table row is removed (it is not clear to me, what is it purposes) and replaced by caption
- Added is version inspired by @Mico answer (+1), but with use of the `align` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip,
            font=small]{caption}
%%%----- Tabellen -------------------------------
\usepackage{tabularray}
%%%----- Math. und Index Abkürzung --------------
\usepackage{mathtools}
    \newcommand\el{el}
    \newcommand\ud{\mathrm{d}}
    \newcommand\dt{\,\ud t}
    \newcommand\m{\mathrm{m}}
    \newcommand\s{\mathrm{S}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Maschinenmodell einer PMSM im dreiphasigen $abc$- koordinatensystem (1)}
\label{tab: Maschinenmodell_PMSM_abc_Tabelle_1}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vline{1,2,Z},
             colspec = {l Q[r, mode=math] @{\;} X[l, mode=math]},
             rowsep=5pt
             }
Statorkreis:        & u_{\s}^{abc}(t)
                        & = R_{\s} \cdot i_{\s}^{abc}(t) + \frac{\ud}{\dt} \psi_{\s}^{abc}(t)   \\ 
verkettete Flüsse:  & \psi_{\s}^{abc}(t)
                        & = \psi_{\s}^{abc}\Bigl(i_{\s}^{abc}(t),\ \phi_{\m}(t)\biggr)               \\
Mechanik:           & \frac{\ud}{\dt} \omega_{\m}(t)
                        & = \frac{1}{\theta_{\m}} \cdot \bigl(m_{\m}(t) - m_{\mathrm{l}}(t) \bigr)  \\
Elektrische Signale:& \omega_{\el}(t)
                        & = p \cdot \omega_{\m}(t) 
                            \quad \textrm{und} \quad 
                            \phi_{\el}(t) = p \cdot \phi_{\m}(t)                            \\ 
Moment:              & m_{\m}(t)
                        & = \begin{multlined}[t][0.8\linewidth]
                            p \cdot i_{\s}^{abc}(t)^{T} \cdot J_{\sum} \cdot \psi_{\s}^{abc}(t) \\
                             \textrm{mit} \quad 
                                i_{\s}^{abc}(t)^{T} = \left( i_{\s}^{a}(t), 
                                i_{\s}^{b}(t), i_{\s}^{c}(t) \right)
                            \end{multlined}                                                        \\ 
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
    
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Maschinenmodell einer PMSM im dreiphasigen $abc$- koordinatensystem (1)}
\label{tab: Maschinenmodell_PMSM_abc_Tabelle_1}
\hrule
\vspace{-1ex}
\begin{align*}
\text{Statorkreis:}        
    && u_{\s}^{abc}(t) & = R_{\s} \cdot i_{\s}^{abc}(t) + \frac{\ud}{\dt} \psi_{\s}^{abc}(t)   \\
\text{verkettete Flüsse:}
    && \psi_{\s}^{abc}(t)
                        & = \psi_{\s}^{abc}\Bigl(i_{\s}^{abc}(t),\ \phi_{\m}(t)\Bigr)               \\
\text{Mechanik:}           
    && \frac{\ud}{\dt} \omega_{\m}(t)
                        & = \frac{1}{\theta_{\m}} \cdot \bigl(m_{\m}(t) - m_{\mathrm{l}}(t) \bigr)  \\
\text{Elektrische Signale:}
    && \omega_{\el}(t)  & = p \cdot \omega_{\m}(t)
                            \quad \textrm{und} \quad
                            \phi_{\el}(t) = p \cdot \phi_{\m}(t)                            \\
\text{Moment:}              
    && m_{\m}(t)        & = \begin{multlined}[t]
                            p \cdot i_{\s}^{abc}(t)^{T} \cdot J_{\sum} \cdot \psi_{\s}^{abc}(t) \\
                             \textrm{mit} \quad
                                i_{\s}^{abc}(t)^{T} = \left( i_{\s}^{a}(t),
                                i_{\s}^{b}(t), i_{\s}^{c}(t) \right)
                            \end{multlined}                               
\end{align*}
\hrule
    \end{table}    
\end{document}
```

[image]